# How to make a screenshot of view with animation in progress

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I need to create blur effect for navigation bar when I'm playing animation on view under it. Animation is pretty simple `CAKeyframeAnimation` instance. But even when I create single snapshot at random moment with any method from list below, it does not work:

- `[UIWindow drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:YES/NO]`
- `[CALayer renderInContext:]`
- `[UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES/NO]`

I see just blank image instead.

Is it possible to capture an animation in motion? Mb there's some different way to blur animation?

Comment: Would using home-plus-power button work in your case, or do you need the screenshot many times and inside your app?

Comment: @meaning-matters, yes, i need the `UIImage` instance that I can use afterwards for blurring and displaying it in navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple use FXBlurView: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

It has a property which does dynamic blurring so you don't have to take screenshots at each point.

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = isDynamic) BOOL dynamic;
```

This property controls whether the FXBlurView updates dynamically, or only once when the view is added to its superview. Defaults to YES. Note that is dynamic is set to NO, you can still force the view to update by calling setNeedsDisplay or updateAsynchronously:completion:. Dynamic blurring is extremely cpu-intensive, so you should always disable dynamic views immediately prior to performing an animation to avoid stuttering. However, if you have mutliple FXBlurViews on screen then it is simpler to disable updates using the setUpdatesDisabled method rather than setting the dynamic property to NO

PS: Make sure you add all frameworks necessary to make it work

Comment: Yep, I've checked this solution too. It doesn't work with CAAnimation as well. It work almost perfectly with tableview, scrollviews and so on.

Comment: Very Imp: Did u make sure that the blur view is on navigation bar and below the animating layers

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to blur a view is to add UIToolbar,just change the alpha value to change the blur.

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initForAutoLayout];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft withInset:0];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight withInset:0];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop withInset:NAVBAR_HEIGHT];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:0];
self.toolbar.alpha = 0.5;
```